# how to rewrite php api request to python?

Tags: python, php, request, base64, hashlib

I have this `php` code for calling API, I'm trying to rewrite it into python and I seem I can't get the accesskey configuration right.

**Php code:**

```
$privateKey = 'privateKey';
$publicKey = 'publicKey';

$parameters = array('status' => 'upcoming');
$postData = json_encode($parameters);
$accessKey = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $postData, $privateKey, true));

$ch = curl_init('https://foundico.com/api/v1/icos/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'X-Foundico-Public-Key: '.$publicKey,
      'X-Foundico-Access-Key: '.$accessKey
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;enter code here
```

**Python code:**

```
import requests.auth
import json
import urllib
import hashlib
import base64
import hmac

public_key = 'mypublickey'
private_key = 'myprivatekey'

parameters = {'status':'upcoming'}
postData=json.dumps(parameters)


accessKey1= hmac.new(private_key.encode("utf8"), postData.encode("utf8"), hashlib.sha256)
accessKey = base64.b64encode(accessKey1.hexdigest().encode('utf8')).decode('utf8')


print(accessKey)
url = 'https://foundico.com/api/v1/icos/'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-Foundico-Public-Key': public_key,
          'X-Foundico-Access-Key': accessKey}
r=requests.post(url,
                #headers=headers,
                #data=postData)
print(r.json()))
```

**Error:** {'error': 480, 'message': 'Private or public key is not valid'}

Answer (score 1):

```
from requests import request
from base64 import b64encode
import hmac
from hashlib import (
    sha256
)
import json

private_key = "private_key".encode()
public_key = "public_key"

post_data = {
    "status": "upcomming"
}

accessKey = b64encode(
    hmac.new(private_key, json.dumps(post_data).encode(), sha256).digest()
).decode()

response = request(
    'POST',
    'https://foundico.com/api/v1/icos/',
    json=post_data,
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Foundico-Public-Key': public_key,
        'X-Foundico-Access-Key': accessKey
    },
    verify=True
)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you seem to `base64_encode()` a binary string returned from `hash_hmac()` as the fourth parameter to `hash_hmac()` is `true`.

However in Python you seem to `base64.b64encode()` a `accessKey1.hexdigest()`, i.e. a **hex-ified** binary string.

You should have a look which methods `accessKey1` provides to get a non-hex digest.

Answer (score 0):

This method is to use `http.client` library in python
Make sure that `Certificates.command` is installed.

```
import requests.auth
import json
import http.client
import urllib
import hashlib
import base64
import hmac

public_key = 'mypublickey'
private_key = 'myprivatekey'

parameters = {'status':'upcoming'}
postData=json.dumps(parameters)


accessKey1= hmac.new(private_key.encode("utf8"), postData.encode("utf8"), hashlib.sha256)
accessKey = base64.b64encode(accessKey1.hexdigest().encode('utf8')).decode('utf8')


print(accessKey)
url = 'https://foundico.com'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-Foundico-Public-Key': public_key,
          'X-Foundico-Access-Key': accessKey}
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(url)
conn.request('POST', '/api/v1/icos', json_data, headers)

response = conn.getresponse()
print(response.read().decode())
```

Comment: is this working for you? I get non-numeric port error and it seems i cant fix it

Comment: @ViliusBikneris sorry i forget to change the url. It should work.